# Does Firebase ref.removeAllObservers() also remove child observers recursively?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have seen a few questions about this but none of them really confirms my query.

If I `.removeAllObservers()` at a parent node, does this also recursively remove all other observers that may have been attached at all child nodes and childs-of-child nodes etc...recursively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API documentation for [`removeAllObservers()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseReference#removeallobservers) states:

> Removes all observers at the current reference, but does not remove
>   any observers at child references. removeAllObservers must be called
>   again for each child reference where a listener was established to
>   remove the observers.

This should be unambiguous.

Comment: yes it is, thanks very much @Doug , should've seen this earlier.